# How to bring specific PushPin on top of all pushpins in bing maps in Store/WP8 app c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I am using Bing.Maps in Store app

this how it is getting overlapped.
[image: Puspin overlapping]

I want the pin should look like this whenever I select the specific pushpin. 
[image: Map apps example]

- I have used 2 different style for pushpins
- on Tapped event I am changing the style of the selected pushpin like this (Maps store app)

  `Pushpin selectedPin = sender as Pushpin;
   selectedPin.Style = (Style)(Resources["SomeStyle"]);`

The problem is other pushpin are getting overlapped on the selected Pin.
is there any way to set the Zindex or any property of the selected pushPin? or any trick to bring the selected pushpin at top of all pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For store app: 
add the selected pushpin to another MapLayer.

Like this: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/06/17/infoboxes-for-native-windows-store-apps.aspx

For WP8 app: 
Remove the selected pin and it again : 
[ZIndex of pushpins in WP7 bing map control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148585/zindex-of-pushpins-in-wp7-bing-map-control)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the pushpin style we can add another push pin on the particular push pin tap event with the same location as the parent pushpin. we can change the position origin of new push pin like this

```
   pushpin.Tap += (s, eve) =>
      {
        MapView.SetView(pushpin.Location,MapView.ZoomLevel);
        var pushpinModel = (s as Pushpin).DataContext;
        GeoCoordinate pinLocation = new GeoCoordinate();
        pinLocation = pushpin.Location;
        pin.PositionOrigin = new PositionOrigin(-0.3,0.7);
        pin.Location = pinLocation;
        MapView.Children.Add(pin);
      }
```

Comment: There is binding in the XAML for the pushpins and the list will get updated in ViewModel. I tried changing the positionOrigin of tapped pushpin but solution didn't work.

Comment: No. You don't change position origin for the tapped pushpin. When you tapping the pushpin you should add the new pushpin with the same Geo-coordinates location and change the position origin. so that it will display on the same place. For the new pushpin you can bind the template which is in XAML. For the refernce you can assign the data context to the first pushpin.

Comment: right, you can remove the pin and add it again, it will be added on top. here is the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148585/zindex-of-pushpins-in-wp7-bing-map-control , this is for WP8 but any solution for Windows store app?